# Problem with activating Spore (four options with languages that are not English)

Tags: origin, spore

I bought Spore (yeah, old game don't judge me) from a 3rd party store.

When I entered the key code to Origin it gave me four options, three are an Asian language, and one is probably Hebrew.

There is not an option for English!

The problem is not with the game, but with the languages, maybe knowing if I can change the game language later can help. At the store, it said that it was in English.

Comment: Which store did you buy it from?  Are you sure you bought an english copy?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I can say which store but it was from Czechia (Doesn't have to be English it can be Czech)

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us where you bought it.  Was it a physical copy? Or an online store like G2A?

Comment: I bought it from ultragame.cz (online store)

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with them; do they pull a G2A and just sell CD keys for super low prices?  If so, chances are good you bought a copy from a different region.

Comment: I don't know but I bought it with bank transfer if that's what you need to know.

Comment: Does the site sell CD keys?  Does it sell them for less than you'd pay buying it directly from EA?

Comment: Yes it sells cd keys but its the same price as on Origin (5 euros)

Comment: Alright, so why would you buy it from a third party instead of Origin?  I'm pretty sure you got sold a different copy than for your region.

Comment: Because they don't support bank transfer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to modify how the game is started.  [There was some information in the old Spore forums about this](http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/1221.page#8494).

PC Example :"C:\Program Files\Electronic Arts\SPORE\Sporebin\SporeApp.exe" –L:en-us

The Languages support are as follows.

- cz-cz: Czech
- da-dk: Danish
- de-de: German
- el-gr: Greek
- en-gb: British
- en-us: American English
- es-es: Spanish
- fi-fi: Finnish
- fr-fr: French
- hu-hu: Hungarian
- it-it: Italian
- nl-nl: Dutch
- no-no: Norwegian
- pl-pl: Polish
- pt-br: Brazilian
- pt-pt: Portuguese
- ru-ru: Russian
- sv-se: Swedish

Additionally an EA community manager [said that the game should determine your language based on your Origin settings](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Spore-language-change/td-p/5247393).

Comment: Should I post a screenshot of the options? Because I haven't picked one yet, I'm waiting for advice.